# Angular2: Send data to MySQL with php file

Tags: php, mysql, angular

I am trying to set a CRUD system with Angular2 and MySQL and PHP, I can get my data with this code:

```
getClients(){
  this.http.get('http://localhost/Angular%20tests/pr1/getClients.php')
  .subscribe(res=>this.clients=res.json(),
            error=> alert("Error get clients"),
            ()=> console.log("Get clients completed..."));
}
```

But for sending the data to the server, I don not understand were is my error, The first three instructions are giving the correct values of my entries.

```
 onPersonneF(f:NgForm){
console.log(f.value);
console.log(JSON.stringify(f.value));
console.log(f.valid);

// test for the post
let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
this.http.post('http://localhost/Angular%20tests/pr1/insertClient.php',   JSON.stringify(f.value), options);
 }
```

And the code of my php file is:

```
<?php
 // for: Blocage d'une requête multi-origines (Cross-Origin Request)
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
 try {
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=test; char=utf8", '****',   '****');

  } catch (Exception $e) {
echo "Connexion Error".$e->getMessage();
 }

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
//var_dump($data);
echo "**************";
echo $data->nom_client;
echo "**************";
$nom_client = $data->nom_client;
$prenom_client = $data->prenom_client;
$no_order = $data->no_order;
$query = $pdo->prepare("insert into clients   values(NULL,'".$nom_client."', '".$prenom_client."', '".$no_order."')");

$query->execute();
$query->closeCursor();
?>
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using PDO you should be using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) with placeholder values and supply any user data only as arguments on `execute` . In this code you have potentially severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Refer to [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) for advice on how to avoid problem like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not send it as JSON, but using [**`URLSearchParams`**](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/index/URLSearchParams-class.html) and headers as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` instead.

```
onPersonneF(f:NgForm){
  let body = new URLSearchParams();
  // obviously set your correct parameters
  body.set('myPropertyName', f.myProperty)
  // the rest of data to send...

  let headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

  this.http.post('http://localhost/Angular%20tests/pr1/insertClient.php', body.toString(), options)
    .map(res => res.json());
    .subscribe(data => console.log(data)) // do subscription in component
}
```

Then you can reach your data in your php-file... here I simply retrurn the data. Remember to `json_encode` what you are returning :)

```
<?php 
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

    $data = file_get_contents("php://input");
    echo json_encode($data);
?>
```